# PrimeFaces selectManyCheckBox don't work with enctype="multipart/form-data"

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectmanycheckbox

I'm having a problem with a form that has the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute and the Primefaces `<p:selectManyCheckBox>`. This is my code:

```html
<f:view xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<h:head />
<h:body id="expiration-body">
    <h:form id="new-expiration-form">
        <div id="form_cargar_grupo">
        <p:messages id="msgs" />

            <div class="form_cargar">
                <label>Resolución:</label>
                <p:fileUpload value="#{expirationViewEdit.file}"
                        mode="simple" required="false" />
            </div>


            <p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{expirationViewEdit.departamentIds}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option1" itemValue="TEST1" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option2" itemValue="TEST2" />
            </p:selectManyCheckbox>

        </div>


        <div class="camp_envio">
            <p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{expirationViewEdit.onSave}" ajax="false" />                 
        </div>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

The problem that I'm having is when I select more than one option of the **selectManyCheckBox**, in my backing bean List there's only one element and after the form is submitted I see that only one check box is selected (the other one gets unselected).

I found out that when I remove the **enctype="multipart/form-data"** attribute of the form the check boxes work fine but I need that property in order to upload files to the server.

Is there any workaround for this? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which PF version? Can't reproduce your problem with 3.4.2.

Comment: Give 3.4.2 a try. It might as well be just a bug in 3.3.

Comment: It didn't work with that version either, I also tried with the "selectManyMenu" and happened the same.

Comment: Well, the problem is caused elsewhere than in the information provided so far. I can't reproduce it in a completely blank playground project with everything set to default.

Comment: Going crazy wih same thing, take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656021/jsf-2-2-selectmanycheck-breaks-javascript

Comment: You have a fix 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262356/file-upload-doesnt-work-with-ajax-in-primefaces-4-0-running-on-jsf-2-2-x/19381134#19381134

Comment: I'm having the exactly same problem with `h:selectManyCheckbox`. If I set form to `enctype="multipart/form-data"` it doesn't work. SelectManyCheckBox sends only 1 value in that case, independently of how many are selected.