# JSF 2.2 SelectManyCheck breaks javascript

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

It used to work perfect on jsf 2.0 but know it renders a box at the end of the screen, with a html table with the data about locations, if I remove the converter the selectmany
checkbox works but it still renders the box.

```
<ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="title">
        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.CreateOfertaTitle}"></h:outputText>
    </ui:define>
            <ui:define name="body">
                <style type="text/css">
            input#chat {
                width: 410px
            }

            #console-container {
                width: 400px;
            }

            #console {
                border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
                border-right-color: #999999;
                border-bottom-color: #999999;
                height: 170px;
                overflow-y: scroll;
                padding: 5px;
                width: 100%;
            }

            #console p {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }
        </style>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
            var Chat = {};

            Chat.socket = null;

            Chat.connect = (function(host) {
                if ('WebSocket' in window) {
                    Chat.socket = new WebSocket(host);
                } else if ('MozWebSocket' in window) {
                    Chat.socket = new MozWebSocket(host);
                } else {
                    Console.log('Error: WebSocket is not supported by this browser.');
                    return;
                }

                Chat.socket.onopen = function() {
                    Console.log('Info: WebSocket connection opened.');
                    document.getElementById('chat').onkeydown = function(event) {
                        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                            Chat.sendMessage();
                        }
                    };
                };

                Chat.socket.onclose = function() {
                    document.getElementById('chat').onkeydown = null;
                    Console.log('Info: WebSocket closed.');
                };

                Chat.socket.onmessage = function(message) {
                    Console.log(message.data);
                };
            });

            Chat.initialize = function() {
                if (window.location.protocol == 'http:') {
                    Chat.connect('ws://' + window.location.host + '/Formosa2/endpoint');
                } else {
                    Chat.connect('wss://' + window.location.host + '/Socket/websocket/chat');
                }
            };

            Chat.sendMessage = (function() {
                var ofertaTexto = document.getElementById('form:texto').value;
                var select = document.getElementById('form:empresaidEmpresa');
                var barrio = document.getElementById('inicio_input').value;

                var nombreEmpresa = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
                    Chat.socket.send(ofertaTexto +', '+ nombreEmpresa+','+ barrio);
                    document.getElementById('chat').value = '';

            });

            var Console = {};

            Console.log = (function(message) {
                var console = document.getElementById('console');
                var p = document.createElement('p');
                p.style.wordWrap = 'break-word';
                p.innerHTML = message;
                console.appendChild(p);
                while (console.childNodes.length > 25) {
                    console.removeChild(console.firstChild);
                }
                console.scrollTop = console.scrollHeight;
            });

            Chat.initialize();

        </script>
        <h:panelGroup id="messagePanel" layout="block">
            <h:messages errorStyle="color: red" infoStyle="color: green" layout="table"/>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <h:outputLabel rendered="#{usuarioController.userSession.isLoggedIn}"
            value="#{usuarioController.userSession.sessionId}"/>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateOfertaLabel_texto}" for="texto" />
                <h:inputText id="texto" value="#{ofertaController.selected.texto}" title="#{bundle.CreateOfertaTitle_texto}" />

                <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateOfertaLabel_inicio}" for="inicio" />
                <t:inputCalendar id="inicio" value="#{ofertaController.selected.inicio}" renderAsPopup="true"
                                 popupTodayString="Hoy" popupDateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy" 
                                 popupWeekString="Semana" helpText="MM/DD/YYYY" forceId="true"/>

                <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateOfertaLabel_fin}" for="fin" />                   
                <t:inputCalendar id="fin" value="#{ofertaController.selected.fin}" renderAsPopup="true"
                                 popupTodayString="Hoy" popupDateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy" 
                                 popupWeekString="Semana" helpText="MM/DD/YYYY" forceId="true"/>

                <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateOfertaLabel_titulo}" for="titulo" />
                <h:inputText id="titulo" value="#{ofertaController.selected.titulo}" title="#{bundle.CreateOfertaTitle_titulo}" />
                <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateOfertaLabel_imagen}" for="imagen" />
                <h:inputFile id="imagen" value="#{ofertaController.upLoad.upFile}" title="#{bundle.CreateOfertaTitle_imagen}"/>

                <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateOfertaLabel_empresaidEmpresa}" for="empresaidEmpresa" />                                        
                <h:selectOneMenu id="empresaidEmpresa" 
                                 value="#{ofertaController.selected.empresaidEmpresa}" 
                                 title="#{bundle.CreateOfertaTitle_empresaidEmpresa}"
                                 required="true" 

                                 requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateOfertaRequiredMessage_empresaidEmpresa}">
                    <f:ajax event="valueChange" execute="empresaidEmpresa" render="ubicacionCollection" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{empresaController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"/>
                </h:selectOneMenu>

                <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateOfertaLabel_ubicacionCollection}" for="ubicacionCollection" />      
                <h:selectManyCheckbox id="ubicacionCollection"
                                      value="#{ofertaController.selected.ubicacionCollection}"
                                      title="#{bundle.CreateOfertaTitle_ubicacionCollection}" >

                    <f:selectItems id="ubicacionCollectionItems"
                                   value="#{ofertaController.selected.empresaidEmpresa.ubicacionCollection}"
                                   var="ubicacionXEmpresa"
                                   itemLabel="#{ubicacionXempresa.barrio}"
                                   itemValue="#{ubicacionXEmpresa}"/>
               </h:selectManyCheckbox>
            </h:panelGrid>
            <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <noscript><h2 style="color: #ff0000">Seems your browser doesn't 
                        support Javascript! Websockets rely on Javascript being enabled. Please enable
                        Javascript and reload this page!</h2></noscript>
                <div>
                    <p>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="type and press enter to chat" id="chat"/>
                    </p>

                    <div id="console-container">
                        <div id="console"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <h:commandLink action="#{ofertaController.create}" value="#{bundle.CreateOfertaSaveLink}" onclick='Chat.sendMessage();'/>
            <br />
            <br />
            <h:commandLink action="#{ofertaController.prepareList}" value="#{bundle.CreateOfertaShowAllLink}" immediate="true"/>
            <br />
            <br />

        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

My convertor:

```
@FacesConverter(value = "ubicacionConverter")
public class UbicacionesBYOfertasConverter implements Converter {

private FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
private OfertaController ofertaController = (OfertaController) facesContext.getApplication()
            .evaluateExpressionGet(facesContext, "#{ofertaController}", OfertaController.class);

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    if (value == null) {
        return null;
    }
    System.out.println(value);
    Ubicacion ubicacion = ofertaController.getSelected().getEmpresaidEmpresa().getUbicacionCollection().iterator().next();        
    ofertaController.getSelected().setUbicacionCollection(ofertaController.getSelected().getEmpresaidEmpresa().getUbicacionCollection());
    return ubicacion;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        Object value) {
    String string = null;
    if (value instanceof Integer) {
        string = String.valueOf(ofertaController.getSelected().getEmpresaidEmpresa().getUbicacionCollection().iterator().next().getIdUbicacion());
    }
    return string;
}   
}
```

Javascript exception

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null jsf.js?       ln=javax.faces&stage=Development:362
contains jsf.js?ln=javax.faces&stage=Development:362
FrameTransport.cleanupReqParams jsf.js?ln=javax.faces&stage=Development:351
FrameTransport.callback jsf.js?ln=javax.faces&stage=Development:335
(anonymous function) jsf.js?ln=javax.faces&stage=Development:380
FrameTransport.open jsf.js?ln=javax.faces&stage=Development:242
AjaxEngine.req.sendRequest jsf.js?ln=javax.faces&stage=Development:1794
sendRequest jsf.js?ln=javax.faces&stage=Development:2440
request jsf.js?ln=javax.faces&stage=Development:2450 
ab jsf.js?ln=javax.faces&stage=Development:3255
onchange List.xhtml:169
```

Comment: You may want to move these JavaScript and CSS code to separate external files or wrap in an ugly `CDATA` tag.

Comment: Didn't worked, any other ideas will be very much appreciated

Comment: the ajax call is killing me

Comment: If I wrap the the selectOneMenu and selectOneCheckBox in a h:form it works perfect, but when I save the record it does not add the selected locations to the current offer

Comment: I found out what it is!!!!!!!!! The enctype data is for the file upload is messing up my selector !!!!!!!

Comment: inputfile most be in other form like this <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">                                
                                <p:fileUpload value="#{contratosMB.fileContrato}" mode="simple" />  
                                <p:commandButton value="Cargar Archivo" ajax="false"  
                                                 actionListener="#{contratosMB.upload}" icon="ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-n"/>  
                            </h:form>

Comment: this is using primefaces

Comment: I got it working with 2 forms now I'm trying to to still keep the behaveiour, (one click save all data), for this I'm using an anctionlistener in the create link and an ajax call on inputfile selected, but ajax breaks js again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okeyyyyyy got ittt working: here's how: 2 separete forms an ajax call an the mojarra javax.faces-2.2.9999...jar

```
                </div>
            <h:commandLink action="#{ofertaController.create}" value="#{bundle.CreateOfertaSaveLink}" onclick='Chat.sendMessage();'/>
            <br />
            <br />
            <h:commandLink action="#{ofertaController.prepareList}" value="#{bundle.CreateOfertaShowAllLink}" immediate="true"/>
            <br />
            <br />
            <h:link outcome="/index" value="#{bundle.CreateOfertaIndexLink}"/>
        </h:form>
        <h:panelGrid id="secondPanel" columns="2">
            <h:form prependId="false" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateOfertaLabel_imagen}" for="imagen" />
                <h:inputFile id="imagen" 
                             value="#{ofertaController.upLoad.upFile}" 
                             title="#{bundle.CreateOfertaTitle_imagen}">
                    <f:ajax  execute="imagen" />
                </h:inputFile>
            </h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

inputfile most be inside other form like this

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">                                
                            <p:fileUpload value="#{contratosMB.fileContrato}" mode="simple" />  
                            <p:commandButton value="Cargar Archivo" ajax="false"  
                            actionListener="#{contratosMB.upload}" icon="ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-n"/>  
</h:form>
```